# Add three string and merge by "-" ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have three strings:

```
first  = "test"
second = "hello"
third  = "world"
```

I want to concatenate them like this:

```
test-hello-world
```

I tried using `+`:

```
first + "-" + second + "-" + third
```

But I'm looking for a better way to do this in Ruby.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

`[first, second, third].join('-')`

Or, if you don't care about variables:

```
%w(test hello world).join('-')
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
[first, second, third].join('-')
```

Answer (score 3):

If they were in an array, you could use `.join`

```
[first, second, third].join('-')
```